# How to use $dateDiff in $elemMatch MongoDB aggregation query condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using `$elemMatch` in an aggregation `$match` step. My simpler `$elemMatch` conditions work just fine, such as equality or comparison, but I can't get it to work when I include a more complex date math condition.

I want to exclude documents where the time elapsed since a date value on the element (`order.timestamp`) is less than a given threshold (i.e. only return documents that have array elements with a date older than X seconds).

I've generally tried many variations of `$dateDiff`, `$cond`, `$expr`, and paths but I can't seem to get anything to work as desired. One attempt of many can be found below. Is there an issue that prevents using `$dateDiff` logic inside an `$elemMatch` field?

```
const match = {
  $match: {
    cardTokens: {
      $elemMatch: {
        owner: null,
        serialNumber: { $gt: 1 },
        releaseDate: { $ne: null, $lte: new Date() },
        order: {
          $gt: [
            {
              $dateDiff: {
                startDate: '$timestamp',
                endDate: new Date(),
                unit: 'seconds',
              },
            },
            60,
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

My data looks approximately like this. I am expecting to match the second document because the second array element with `serialNumber` 10 matches all the `$elemMatch` conditions...

```
[
  {
    "_id": "46f39c4e-ddeb-4ca1-8144-209450137727",
    "items": [
      {
        "serialNumber": 1,
        "owner": {
          "id": "abb02c11-8872-401f-a081-fa5ab97f1574"
        },
        "releaseDate": { "$date": "2021-05-18T13:12:28.794Z" },
        "order": null
      },
      {
        "serialNumber": 10,
        "owner": {
          "id": "2a3e4bb4-7dc0-43c4-bb9a-0e45af23cd49"
        },
        "releaseDate": { "$date": "2020-05-18T20:16:38.985Z" },
        "order": {
          "id": "fd2bf5b8-a3b2-4d29-9c07-c59596f7bc7a",
          "timestamp": { "$date": "2023-03-15T14:19:13.961Z" }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "b6a53532-1b28-4c23-93a2-38d3bb902ead",
    "items": [
      {
        "serialNumber": 1,
        "owner": null,
        "releaseDate": null,
        "order": null
      },
      {
        "serialNumber": 10,
        "owner": null,
        "releaseDate": { "$date": "2021-12-02T03:23:36.520Z" },
        "order": {
          "id": "f2bb864d-cf92-4617-9789-a895748b4e6c",
          "timestamp": { "$date": "2021-04-27T10:18:03.190Z" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your approach, it stems from these 3 facts:

1. `$dateDiff` is an aggregation operator, thus it cannot be used in a `$match` stage unless wrapped by the `$expr` operator.
2. `$expr` has to be at the top level of the `$match` stage
3. `$elemMatch` is not an aggregation operators, thus it cannot be used inside an `$expr` operator.

So basically combining these 3 operators is impossible. as `$expr` has to be on top, you need the `$dateDiff` to be within it but `$elemMatch` cannot be used within it.

So what you need to do is just use some other aggregation operators to achieve these, they might have some overhead compared to elemMatch but it's the best we've got. You can get this done in multiple ways, here is what I consider to be the most straight forward using `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$cardTokens",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.owner",
                        null
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        "$$this.serialNumber",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        "$$this.releaseDate",
                        "$$NOW"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $gt: [
                        {
                          $dateDiff: {
                            startDate: "$$this.order.timestamp",
                            endDate: "$$NOW",
                            unit: "second"
                          }
                        },
                        60
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VMnv-f8FSVV)

Comment: That's a very interesting combination of `$gt`, `$size`, and `$filter` to recreate an `$elemMatch`. This seems to do the trick! Thank you!

Comment: +100000 of Karma for obscure knowledge revealed